# Mean diameter of the collar when calculating the raising torque

Tags: torque

#### TL;DR

- Is it possible to calculate the mean diameter of a collar?
- Can I ignore the collar's component when calculating the raising torque?

---

I have been trying to [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/z-axis-stepper-motor-and-lead-screw-torque-calculation/9827#9827) this question, [Z axis: Stepper motor and lead screw torque calculation](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/z-axis-stepper-motor-and-lead-screw-torque-calculation), over on the [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com) site.

I obtained an equation for the raising torque from
[Torque Required to Raise Load (TR) Calculation](https://ncalculators.com/mechanical/torque-required-raise-load-calculator.htm) and the *full* [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G23E.jpg), for *both* thread and collar, is given by:

$$T_R = \frac{Fd_m}{2}\left(\frac{l+\pi\mu{d_m}}{\pi{d_m}-\mu{l}}\right)+\left(\frac{F\mu_cd_c}{2}\right)$$

Neither of the mean diameters for the square thread, nor the collar were given.

However, I found that the mean diameter of the square thread can be  determined from the pitch, $l$, and nominal diameter, $d_n$, by

$$d_m = d_n-\frac{l}{2}$$

However, I do not know how to calculate the mean diameter of the collar. I was hoping that it would simply be

$$d_c = d_n+\frac{l}{2}$$

but, I think that might be incorrect, although I am not sure - as this would seem to be the formula for calculating the major diameter of the screw, when given its mean diameter.

Looking at a [series of tutorials](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/%7Enrskumar/Index_files/Mech344/Solutions/Problem%20Set%206-Chapter%2010_Power%20Screws%20and%20Fasteners-Selected%20Problems.pdf), I see that the mean diameter of the collar may need to be provided. For example, from Solution 10.3

[image: Diagram of load, screw and collar]

After reading around the topic, I see that often the component relating to the collar's friction is discarded (or, as the tutorials state, considered to be eliminated). Why is that? Is that a common simplification?  The OP had this simplified version of the above formula in their question,

$$T_R = \frac{Fd_m}{2}\left(\frac{l+\pi\mu{d_m}}{\pi{d_m}-\mu{l}}\right)$$

So, do I actually need to worry about the collar's mean diameter?

Comment: How could it be possible to calculate the collar diameter from the thread dimensions? Surely the collar can be made any size greater than the thread diameter. The bigger it is, the bigger the torque needed to overcome its friction, so the diameter can be important. That seems too obvious so am I missing something? If you can show that collar friction is negligible, then discard it. Perhaps if it's on roller bearings and the thread isn't, then you can do a rough estimate of the friction to show that it's negligible for any reasonable collar diameter.

Comment: Yes, I slowly started to realise that it can't be calculated... :-). Thanks for the confirmation. I also saw a few days ago, that if there are no bearings (which there aren't) then it can not be neglected, so it would seem rather difficult to answer the question on the stepper calculation as I am unsure what counts as the collar diameter. Is it just the nut around the threaded rod, or does the weight of the x-axis gantry, which sits upon that nut, also have to be accounted for? Also, as there are two stepper motors for the z-axis, then how does that affect the calculation? It is a can of worms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to calculate the collar diameter from the thread dimensions. The collar can be made any size greater than the thread diameter. The bigger it is, the bigger the torque needed to overcome its friction, so the diameter can be important. If you can show that collar friction is negligible, then discard it. Perhaps if it's on roller bearings and the thread isn't, then you can do a rough estimate of the friction to show that it's negligible for any reasonable collar diameter.